# Family Database in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have written a program in Prolog for the database of a family. I have defined a few predicates like `mother_of`, `father_of`, `son_of` , `grandparent(G,X)`. I was supposed to define the above-mentioned rules. I am new to Prolog. Can someone please let me know if my code is right or if I am on the right path?

```
man(dan).
man(joe).
man(paul).
woman(marry).
woman(susie).
parent(joe,susie). % means adam is parent of peter
parent(joe,dan) :- child(dan,joe).
parent(marry,susie).
parent(giuseppe,margaret).
    parent(giuseppe,evelyn).
    parent(giuseppe,robert).
    parent(giuseppe,grace).
    parent(giuseppe,fred).
    parent(giuseppe,mary).
    parent(giuseppe,estelle).
    parent(albina,margaret).
    parent(albina,evelyn).
    parent(albina,robert).
    parent(albina,grace).
parent(albina,fred).
    parent(albina,mary).
    parent(albina,estelle).
    parent(ida,catherine).
    parent(ida,juanita).
    parent(ida,edythe).
    parent(ida,george).
    parent(johnMiddleton,catherine).
    parent(georgeAlexandar,juanita).
    parent(georgeAlexandar,edythe).
    parent(georgeAlexandar,george).
    parent(estelle,steve).
    parent(estelle,judy).
    parent(estelle,david).
    parent(estelle,marilyn).
    parent(estelle,john).
    parent(george,steve).
    parent(george,judy).
    parent(george,david).
    parent(george,marilyn).
    parent(george,john).
    parent(marry,dan).
father_of(F,C):-man(F),parent(F,C).
mother_of(M,C):-woman(M),parent(M,C).
son_of(C,F) :-man(C),child(C,F).
brother(B,P) :- man(B),
                    mother(M,B),
                    mother(M,P),
                    father(F,B),
                    father(F,P).
sister(S,P) :- woman(S),
                    mother(M,S),
                    mother(M,P),
                    father(F,S),
                    father(F,P).

grandparent(G,X) :- parent(G,P),
                        parent(P,X).                   

grandparent(G,john).
```

Comment: Euh, where did you define any `child/2` predicates?

Comment: parent(joe,dan) :- child(dan,joe).

Comment: that's only on the right of the clause, since you never define a predicate `child/2`(as clause or as facts), any `child` query will return with `false`.

Comment: Furthermore `grandparent(G,john).` Doesn't make much sense, it seems to imply everyone is the grandparent of `john`.

Comment: thanks for the guidance. Can you please edit the code or give any hint?

Comment: can I say     child(evelyn, giuseppe. for instance?

Answer (score 0):

I have added

```
child(C, P) :-
  parent(P, C).
```

and commented out

```
% parent(joe,dan) :- child(dan,joe).
```

and

```
% grandparent(G, john).
```

Now you can try

```
?- child(evelyn, giuseppe).
true .
```

as expected.

All the code for your reference

```
man(dan).
man(joe).
man(paul).

woman(marry).
woman(susie).

parent(joe, susie).
% Do not use this as it cause stack overflow due to child/2 definition later on
parent(joe, dan).
% :- child(dan, joe).
parent(marry, susie).
parent(giuseppe, margaret).
parent(giuseppe, evelyn).
parent(giuseppe, robert).
parent(giuseppe, grace).
parent(giuseppe, fred).
parent(giuseppe, mary).
parent(giuseppe, estelle).
parent(albina, margaret).
parent(albina, evelyn).
parent(albina, robert).
parent(albina, grace).
parent(albina, fred).
parent(albina, mary).
parent(albina, estelle).
parent(ida, catherine).
parent(ida, juanita).
parent(ida, edythe).
parent(ida, george).
parent(johnMiddleton, catherine).
parent(georgeAlexandar, juanita).
parent(georgeAlexandar, edythe).
parent(georgeAlexandar, george).
parent(estelle, steve).
parent(estelle, judy).
parent(estelle, david).
parent(estelle, marilyn).
parent(estelle, john).
parent(george, steve).
parent(george, judy).
parent(george, david).
parent(george, marilyn).
parent(george, john).
parent(marry, dan).

father_of(F, C) :-
    man(F),
    parent(F, C).

mother_of(M, C) :-
    woman(M),
    parent(M, C).

son_of(C, F) :-
    man(C),
    child(C, F).

brother(B, P) :-
    man(B),
    mother(M, B),
    mother(M, P),
    father(F, B),
    father(F, P).

sister(S, P) :-
    woman(S),
    mother(M, S),
    mother(M, P),
    father(F, S),
    father(F, P).

grandparent(G, X) :-
    parent(G, P),
    parent(P, X).

% ???
% grandparent(G, john).

child(A, B) :-
    parent(B, A).
```